# How to control auto-casting of class object instance to string?

Tags: swift, string, class, casting

As example I have the following class

```
class myClass {
   var someValue1: Double = 1.1
   var someValue2: Double = 2.0
}
```

What I need to code to have ability to print some specific value into the String due to Auto Casting process?

As example: to print `someValue2` value with the following code:

```
print("\(instanceOfMyClass)") // expected output: "2.0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it, by extending a class with [CustomStringConvertible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible) protocol.

```
class MyClass {
   var someValue1: Double = 1.1
   var someValue2: Double = 2.0
} 

extension myClass: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "\(someValue2)"
    }
}

let a = MyClass()

print(a)
```

**Output:** 2.0